# JNI: NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Output of: javap -s SomeClass

```
public org.someapp.SomeClass$_data data;
  Signature: Lorg/someapp/SomeClass$_data;
```

Definition of SomeClass in Java:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private class _data {
        byte[] something = new byte[1234];
    }

    public _data data;
}
```

Definition of native function in Java:

```
public static native int NativeFunction(SomeClass something);
```

Java implementation:

```
SomeClass x = new SomeClass();
NativeInterface.NativeFunction(x);
```

However, when the following code is executed:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_someapp_NativeInterface_NativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jobject someobject) {
    jclass some_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, someobject);
    jfieldID data = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, some_class, "data", "Lorg/someapp/SomeClass$_data"); 
}
```

Java throws a "NoSuchFieldError;: data" exception on the GetFieldID call. I don't get it.. The signature is just fine (copied straight from javap).

Note that getting the field ID for a simpler variable, like an unsigned short (with signature "S") works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a feeling that `"Lorg/someapp/SomeClass$_data"` should be `"Lorg/someapp/SomeClass$_data;"`.  Note the semicolon.

Comment: Such a small mistake.. Thanks so much :)